# What is the name of the linux API that hints sequential or random access read?

Tags: c++, linux, api

There is an API call under linux that I forgot the name of.

You can essentially hint to the system how you'll be mostly accessing the file and it'll tune performance accordingly.

Can anyone recall the api function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [`posix_fadvise()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html)?

Comment: Which, on Linux, is a wrapper around the system call [`fadvise64_64`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fadvise64).

Comment: That's the one.  Does it make a lot of difference for sequentially read or written data?

Comment: I have no idea how much difference it would make.  I imagine that it can't hurt, as long as you don't lie to it.